# How can I create an angularjs directive that makes a ajax request?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to achieve the following result:

```
<users name="allUsers" get-all></users>
```

And then, render a select element with a list of all users. This is what I did until now:

```
var app = angular.module("Security", []);

app.directive("users", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
    };
});

app.directive("getAll", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A'
    };
});
```

After lots of googling, I found nothing related. Probably I am searching for rats instead of dogs...

EDIT:
OK, now I have a service, but still don't know how to connect using scope.

```
app.factory('userService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getAll: function () {
            return $http.get('/users/getAll')
                        .then(function (result) {
                            return result.data;
                            // [{Id: 1, Name: 'John'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'Mark'}]
                        });
        }
    }
});

app.directive("getAll", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^users',
        template: '<option value="{{Id}}">{{Name}}</option>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, userCtrl) {
            userService.getAll()
                       .then(function (result) {
                           // What should I do?
                       });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: well, usually you would use a service to send the ajax request, and then make the directive depend on it. however, i'm not sure how good of an idea sending an ajax request in a directive would be due to how many times that request will be sent during a digest cycle. Wrong tool for the job (which would explain lack of search results).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What I really want to achieve is a easy reuse for this "component", because this is used very often. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could make it a view and give the view it's own controller/template that you reuse for multiple routes.

Comment: Thank you again. Can you point me some example?

Comment: Nope, not without searching for one myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it.

```
var userModule = angular.module("Users", []);

userModule.factory('userService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getAll: function () {
            return $http.get('/security/users/getAll')
                        .then(function (result) {
                            return result;
                        });
        }
    }
}]);

userModule.directive("users", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<select><option ng-repeat="item in collection" value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</option></select>',
        scope: true
    };
});

userModule.directive("getAll", ['userService', function (service) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope) {
            service.getAll()
                   .then(function (result) {
                       scope.collection = result.data;
                   });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<users get-all></users>
```